# Get File Id and Folder Id

Tags: netsuite

I have to get the id of the folder and file from the cabinet in suitescript.
I have the file name, which I get from a custom field.
How to get the id of the file and folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a search for this. Something like ,

```
var filename = '******';//your file name goes here
var filter = new nlobjSearchFilter('name', 'file', 'is', filename);
var column = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', 'file');
var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('folder', null , filter , column);

if(searchResult != null){
   var folderId = searchResult[0].getId();
   var fileId = searchResult[0].getValue('internalid','file');       
}
```

Comment: you can also use a saved search for this